# How to select only visible elements in search result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of elements with a checkbox for each elements.
I added a checkAll button to select all my elements.

http://jsbin.com/dipumemo/3  ([edit](http://jsbin.com/dipumemo/3/edit))

**How can I improve my user interface and select only visible elements when I click on "checkAll" button ?**

my workflow:

1. append 1 in filter (hide with display:none; list 2)
2. click on checkboxAll
3. clear filter
4. See only list1 checked

[image]
[image]

My html:

```
<div ng-app="listsModule">
    <div ng-controller="listsController">
        <input type="text" id="filter_lists" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search a list">

        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll"/></th>
                <th>List name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="list in lists | filter:search | orderBy:'name'">
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="list.isSelected" ng-checked="checkAll"></td>
                <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ list.isSelected }}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('listsModule', []);

app.controller('listsController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.lists = [
        {"id": 39, "name": "list1", "isSelected": false},
        {"id": 40, "name": "list2", "isSelected": false}
    ]
});
```

Comment: It's actually a little inconsistent, can you see it? When you clear filter and "Check all" is checked everything that is *visible* **should** be checked.

Comment: @dfsq is that it is a question? do I improve my question?

Comment: I mean you are actually trying to make user interface worse, because ever if you succeed it will make an application inconsistent.

Comment: @dfsq I don't think so :) look at gmail. Make a research, and click on checkbox all. Gmail select only the elements in the page and add a warning message: `All 20 conversations on this page are selected. Select all conversations that match this search` IMO the other way is counter-intuitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the way that the list is filtered will give you access to the filtered list in your current scope.  Then you can get your selected items from that filtered list.  Adding a watch to your checkAll will let you toggle selection of your filtered items.

html:

```
<div ng-app="listsModule">
    <div ng-controller="listsController">
        <input type="text" id="filter_lists" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search a list">

        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll"/></th>
                <th>List name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="list in filtered = (lists | filter:{name:search}) | orderBy:'name'">
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="list.isSelected"></td>
                <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ list.isSelected }}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>Selected:
            <div ng-repeat="list in filtered | filter:{isSelected:true} | orderBy:'name'">
                {{list.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("listsModule", []);

app.controller('listsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.lists = [
        {"id": 39, "name": "Fluffy", "isSelected": false},
        {"id": 40, "name": "Muffy", "isSelected": false},
        {"id": 41, "name": "Dingo Jr.", "isSelected": false},
        {"id": 42, "name": "Bertram", "isSelected": false}
    ];

    $scope.$watch('checkAll', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if ($scope.filtered)
        for (i=0; i<$scope.filtered.length; i++) {
            $scope.filtered[i].isSelected = newValue;
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: thank you work like a charm, the solution is pretty clean. I added the jsbin